# Tensorflow: use the whole validation dataset to validate the network, how to implement it with Queue

Tags: tensorflow

I have a validation dataset containing 10k samples, stored in a [`TFRecords`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/python_io#tfrecords_format_details) file. I use a Queue to read the file as the input to the network, and I set the `batch_size` to 128. Since 10k / 128 = 78.125, so the queue can dequeue 78 times but leave the rest (10k - 128 * 78 = 16) samples not validated, because after 78 times dequeue operations, the program will throw an OutOfRangeError.

However, I do want to validate the exact 10k samples including the final 16. How to do it in TensorFlow with a queue?

Comment: 16 out of 10k is not a lot, but if you really want to include them, you can feed the last batch as a shorter batch, but then you need to use `None` in your placeholder shape. Another option is take the remaining 16 and evaluate them individually at the end.

Comment: You can also consider setting the batch size to 125.

Comment: The left 16 samples cannot evaluated via queue, can it?

Answer (score 0):

Neal's comment is a good solution:  First, you can set the batch size to an exact multiple of your dataset size.  Alternately, you can run the final "trailing" examples manually using feed_dict and add their results to whatever you're tracking.